# Listar nombre y unidades del disco con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Como puedo listar las unidades de mi disco en Python.

Salida:
C:\
D:\
E:\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando la librería `os` podrás utilizar comando del sistema operativo pero todo dependerá de que sistema operativo estés utilizando, que supongo que es windows por el nombre de las etiquetas, aun asi te dejo el ejemplo en windows y linux.

En windows

```
import os
print(os.system('fsutil fsinfo drives'))
```

En linux

```
import os
print(os.system('df -h'))
```

Si tienes alguna duda o no funciona, házmelo saber.